# How to open an excel file that is already open without getting permission denied

Tags: python, excel

I need to do something with data in an excel file. I therefore open the excel file with the .read_excel method of the pandas library. I only read the data, I don't need to write to the file. However I often have to adjust something in the excel file and run the code again. In order to be able to run the code again, I always need to close the excel file (in the windows UI) which is very annoying. If I don't do this I get "Permission denied".

I therefore thought, okay lets just make a copy, read the copy and delete the copy after the script. However it does not even allow me to make a copy. I tried shutil.copyfile.

I am running windows and autosave is on for this excel file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas' `read_excel` method uses openpyxl as engine if the file format is .xlsx.
openpyxl in turn can accept keyword arguments one of them being `read_only=True`.

So it is just a matter of adding that to you `pd.read_excel` call like:

```
pd.read_excel(...,engine_kwargs={"read_only":True})
```

Comment: still getting permission denied. Pycharm also colors the call yellow. It seems like it doesn't recognize the engine_kwargs keyword

Comment: Doing this now: df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name="FUNCTION_2_FEATURE", engine='openpyxl', engine_kwargs={"read_only":True})

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? `engine_kwargs` is defined in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Also, is the extension of your Excel file `xlsx`, `xlsm` or is it the old `xls`?

Comment: It is xlsx, I'll check the version when I am home